# Warning to user about reverse image search should not be displayed to non-post-owner

Tags: bug, editing

When I was editing [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/19119/revisions), which is an [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request), I forgot to edit the title and hit submit, and I got a message about another existing question with the same title (which is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)) and another message about using Reverse Image Search before posting image identification question.

It doesn't make any sense, since there is no point in non-post-owner editors to be notified about it. It's just simply noise.

Can we disable the Reverse Image Search warning for non-post-owner editor?